Angular 17.3 new project error, in node.js 18.16
I install node-v18.16.1, then update angular v17.3,
I created new project- ng new, then ng serve,
the project is empty, base base project
I get an error:
the error:
[error] Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
    at ensureServiceIsRunning (C:\Repos\HolocaustSurvivorsInterfaces\mlm-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2164:29)
    at context (C:\Repos\HolocaustSurvivorsInterfaces\mlm-app\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2048:33)
    at #performBundle (C:\Repos\HolocaustSurvivorsInterfaces\mlm-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\tools\esbuild\bundler-context.js:158:68)
    at BundlerContext.bundle (C:\Repos\HolocaustSurvivorsInterfaces\mlm-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\tools\esbuild\bundler-context.js:132:49)
    at C:\Repos\HolocaustSurvivorsInterfaces\mlm-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\tools\esbuild\bundler-context.js:65:28
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at BundlerContext.bundleAll (C:\Repos\HolocaustSurvivorsInterfaces\mlm-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\tools\esbuild\bundler-context.js:61:67)
    at executeBuild (C:\Repos\HolocaustSurvivorsInterfaces\mlm-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\application\execute-build.js:40:67)


Try to remove the node_modules folder and run "npm i" command again.

still the same error :(

More details are required then to check what happens :) can you provide the repo or some way to reproduce the problem?

how can i send you the repo?
